# Laravel redirect() doesn't work on chaining method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have simple model on `laravel` and I would like to use PHP Object Oriented to save or update data inside the `Controller`. All methods of my solution work fine but I can't redirect.

### Model

```
class RechargeRangeCard extends Model
{
    protected $table = "recharge_range_cards";
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    private $request;

    public function data(StoreRechargeRangeCard $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        return $this;
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = RechargeRangeCard::create(
            [
                'minimum' => $this->request->input('minimum_range'),
                'maximum' => $this->request->input('maximum_range'),
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            ]
        );

        return $this;
    }

    public function redirect()
    {
        return redirect()->to('rechargeRangecards');
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public function store(StoreRechargeRangeCard $request)
{
    $class = new RechargeRangeCard();
    $class->data($request)->store()->redirect();
}
```

In this chaining method `redirect()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the redirect from the Controller method in order for it to work:

```
public function store(StoreRechargeRangeCard $request)
{
    $class = new RechargeRangeCard();
    return $class->data($request)->store()->redirect();
}
```

However, I'd just like to point out that this is mixing your concerns. Redirecting is strictly a concern of the controller; your model shouldn't have any clue about that, or even that it's possible.

Comment: Oh!! Thanks sir, very helpful reply